# Изучаю docker, как это работает?

Tags: python, django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Я совершенно запутался в работе докера. Хочу просто запустить простенький тестовый бэк на джанго + gunicorn + nginx. Вводные данные:
Dockerfile web:

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-openbsd

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY req.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r req.txt

COPY . /app
```

Dockerfile nginx

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.20.2'

services:
  web:
    build: ./
    command: gunicorn gems.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_vol:/app/static
    expose:
      - 8000
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    volumes:
      - static_vol:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  static_vol:
```

файловая система проекта на хосте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Команда которую я использую для создания контейнера

```
docker-compose build
```

Команда которую я использую для запуска контейнера

```
docker-compose up
```

Так же когда хочу пересобрать контейнер использую

```
docker-compose down
```

Вопросы:

1. С самого начала у меня по какой-то причине req.txt у меня находился и в корне /app и в папке static в обоих контейнерах(nginx, web). И в папке static кроме req.txt ничего не было, хотя как я думал там должны быть файлы из static хоста. Это ладно выполнил:
   `python manage.py collectstatic`
   Статика admin drf появилась. Как я понял когда монтируешь и связываешь тома между контейнерами они по умолчанию должны быть пустыми внутри контейнера? Почему в моем случае там был req.txt?
2. Для эксперимента я удалил абсолютно все images и containers. То есть после команд:
   `docker images -a`
   `docker container ls -a`
   было пусто. Начал собирать заново и вдруг те файлы которые я добавил в удаленном контейнере до удаления уже есть в новом. Окей, я удалил эти файлы внутри контейнра зайдя в него с помощью exec. сделал down опять удалил все образы и контейнеры и заново создаю и опять эти файлы там есть. Так вот, объясните как и откуда докер подтягивает эти файлы и есть ли способ создать контейнер не основыаясь на прошлом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как я понял когда монтируешь и связываешь тома между контейнерами они по умолчанию должны быть пустыми внутри контейнера?

Нет, если `volume` монтируется в уже существующую папку в контейнере, то весь контент автоматически копируется из папки в контейнере в этот `volume`. [Docker Volume Doc](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container):

> If you start a container which creates a new volume, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted such as /app/, **Docker copies** the directory’s contents into the volume.

Кстати, это поведение отличается для bind mounts, если вы что-то в существующую папку в контейнере, то оно просто "скроет" данные в контейнер, а поверх покажет привязанную папку.

> Почему в моем случае там был req.txt?

Чесно почему у вас там оказался `req.txt` я не знаю. У вас один и тот же `volume` привязан к двум контейнера, т.е. он является общим между двумя контейнерами и изменения сделанные в одном - видны для другого. Возможно вы случайно его скопировали в папку `static`, он попал в `volume`, а т.к. он автоматически не удаляется, то он оставался при перезапусках. Смотрите следующий пункт.

> Так вот, объясните как и откуда докер подтягивает эти файлы и есть ли способ создать контейнер не основыаясь на прошлом?

Вы написали что удаляли все и проверяли это командами `docker images ...` и `docker container`, но у вас в `docker-compose.yml` есть `volumes`. Они автоматически создаются при выполнении команды `docker compose up ...` и **не** удаляются при `docker compose down ...`. Это достаточно логично, т.к. образ это read only snapshot файловой системы, контейнер имеет "временную" файловую систему, которая после перезапуска сбросится на состояние из образа,   а нужно ещё какое-то хранилище, чтобы сохранять данные (например для базы данныех). Для этого есть bind mounts или volumes. Поэтому вам нужно ещё проверять `docker volume ...`.

Команда `docker compose down` поддерживает флаг `-v`, который как раз и будет удалять `volumes`.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, флаг порешал все проблемы